# Angular 8 Nested subscribes

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I'm doing a get request in order to retrieve the user role

```
private myOrders;
constructor(private userData: UserDataService) {
  this.userData.getUser().subscribe((user: any) => {
    //and then I'm doing a conditional get 
    if (user.role == "Admin") {
      this.userData.getAdminOrders().subscribe((adminOrders: any) => {
        this.myOrders = adminOrders
      });
    } else {
      this.myOrders = user.orders
    }
  });
```

My app shows properly only the user.orders (the orders for the normal customers) but when I'm with the Admin account it only shows the first page load but then they disappear.

How can I manage those nested subscribtion? (They are http.get on my userDataService)

Answer (score 5):

You should use one of the [rxjs](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/operators) operators on this type of cases.

For this case I recommend you [flatMap](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/flatMap):

```
private myOrders;
constructor(private userData: UserDataService) {
  this.userData.getUser().pipe(flatMap(user: any) => {
    if (user.role == "Admin") {
      return this.userData.getAdminOrders();
    } else {
      return of(user.orders)
    }
  }).suscribe((result) => {
        this.myOrders = result
    }
  );
```

If `user.role == "Admin"` is true, `result` will be the result of the HTTP request in `this.userData.getAdminOrders()`. On the other case, the result will be `user.orders`.

Answer (score 3):

You can avoid using nested subscriptions by using one of the "Higher Order Mapping Operators" [LINK](https://blog.angular-university.io/rxjs-higher-order-mapping/)

This is just a fancy way of saying: operators that map the incoming value to another observable, subscribe to it, and emit those values. They also manage these "inner subscriptions" automatically.

The [`switchMap`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap) will "switch" to a new observable whenever a new value is received.  So, when you pass in the "user", map it to the appropriate observable based on the `user.role`, it will subscribe to it and emit those values.  When a new "user" value is received, it will unsubscribe from the previous observables, and subscribe to the new one.

Also, rather than subscribing in your component, you can define "myOrders" to be an Observable, which you can subscribe to in the template, like this:

```
public myOrders$ = this.userData.getUser().pipe(
    switchMap(user => { 
        return user.role = 'Admin' 
            ? this.userData.GetAdminOrders() 
            : of(user.orders));
        }
    );
```

Then, you can use the [`async`](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe) pipe in your template.  This means you don't need to worry about managing subscriptions in your component.

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="order of myOrders$ | async">{{ order.description }}</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

Uses `switchMap` operator and observable `iif` and `of`

```
this.userData.getUser()
  .pipe(
    switchMap(({ role, orders }) =>
      iif(
        () => role === 'Admin',
        this.userData.getAdminOrders(),
        of(orders),
      ),
    ),
  )
  .subscribe(orders => (this.myOrders = orders));
```

never use a subscribe in another subscribe, because you create memory leacks,
or for a cleaner and better solution, use async pipe as specified by **@BizzyBob**