# angular - Error handling with nested subscriptions - Chain multiple api-calls

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, httpclient

I'm building an angular app with a login/registration flow, and ATM I'm looking for an easy and more readable way to code the following:

```
register() {
    this.accountService.register(this.user, this.password, this.passwordConfirmation).subscribe(() => {
        this.accountService.login(this.user.email, this.password).subscribe((loginResult) => {
            this.accountService.csrfRefresh().subscribe(() => {
                if (loginResult.status === ELoginStatus.success) {
                    this.router.navigateByUrl(this.returnUrl);
                } else {
                    this.errorMessage$.next('Login unsuccessful');
                }
            }, () => {
                this.errorMessage$.next('Login unsuccessful');
            })
        }, () => {
            this.errorMessage$.next('Login unsuccessful');
        })
    }, () => {
        this.errorMessage$.next('Login unsuccessful');
    });
}
```

With this code I need to write the error handling code 4 times, or create a seperate method, or pass data on to a `BehaviorSubject`. This seems to be sluggish.

Something I've been considering is to use `await`:

```
async register() {
    try {
        await this.accountService.register(this.user, this.password, this.passwordConfirmation).toPromise();
        const loginResult = await this.accountService.login(this.user.email, this.password).toPromise();
        await this.accountService.csrfRefresh().toPromise();

        // TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'
        if (loginResult!.status === ELoginStatus.success) {
            this.router.navigateByUrl(this.returnUrl);
        } else {
            this.errorMessage$.next('Login unsuccessful');
        }
    } catch (exception) {
        this.errorMessage$.next('Login unsuccessful');
    }
}
```

This is a lot better, but I was hoping to avoid `async/await`, and the need to use `.toPromise()` on Observables.

What's the recommended way to chain these 3 api-calls?

Comment: Check out this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61263588/7365461. You can use `switchMap, mergeMap, concatMap` to do it and these three all have small differences. If the small differences doesn't matter, I usually just use `switchMap`. You can learn about the differences here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49701944/7365461.

Comment: switchMap would probably help with your observable chaining

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to re-write this logic in a more idiomatic rxjs way like this

```
register() {
    this.accountService.register(this.user, this.password, this.passwordConfirmation).pipe(
      concatMap(() => this.accountService.login(this.user.email, this.password)),
      concatMap((loginResult) => {
        if (loginResult.status === ELoginStatus.success) {
           return this.router.navigateByUrl(this.returnUrl)
        }
        throw new Error("Login unsuccessful")
      })
    )
    .subscribe({
      next: data => {
            // process any result in case of success
            },
      error: () => this.errorMessage$.next('Login unsuccessful')
    })
}
```

As you see i tend to use `concatMap` when i need to compose more than one call to http, since `concatMap` implies that we wait for the response of the previous call before we move to the second.

`switchMap` is the right operator if we want to "kill on fly requests' when new requests come in.

`mergeMap` should be used when you want to manage more requests in parallel, but it comes with its own complexities.

Maybe you can find [some inspiration here](https://medium.com/me/stats/post/ef636c9af19a).